# Use only one instance of Media Payer to play multiple audio files in android

Tags: java, android, audio

I have a class that plays audio files located in some folders...Problem is i cant manage to use only one instance of the Media Player to play multiple audio files. Every time i attempt to play a different song, a new instance of the Media Class is created and the new song plays in parallel with the previous one which is really annoying...Can anyone help me use only one instance of the Media Payer to play different songs, one after the other like in normal audio players

```
//The files are listed as an array into a ListView, so i added a ListView.OnItemClickListener to play that location which the user has selected
ListView audiolist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.audiolist);
 audiolist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(position==id){

                    File mypath=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                    String mystring=(String)audiolist.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    if(mystring.contains(".mp3")) {
                        File myfile = new File(mypath.toString(), "/" + mystring);
                        Uri newuri = Uri.fromFile(myfile);
    //I think this line is the one creating the mutiple instances of the MediaPayer
                    mp=new MediaPlayer();
                             mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                       mp.setAudioAttributes(
                               new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                                .build()
                       );
                              try {
                                    mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),newuri);
                                    mp.setDisplay(holder);
                                    mp.prepare();
                                    mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(Audio_Player.this);
                                    mycontroller=new MediaController(Audio_Player.this);
                                    mycontroller.setMediaPlayer(Audio_Player.this);
                                    mp.start();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                      }//end of if
                       });//end of listview method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause**

Every time users click on an item of a `ListView`, you always create a new `MediaPlayer` instance and do not stop the current one. That explains why you see multiple audios are playing at the same time.

**Solution**

Just create a new `MediaPlayer` instance if there is no one existing, otherwise, stop the current one before playing the new one. Change your code from

```
File mypath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
String mystring = (String)audiolist.getItemAtPosition(position);
if (mystring.contains(".mp3")) {
    File myfile = new File(mypath.toString(), "/" + mystring);
    Uri newuri = Uri.fromFile(myfile);
    // I think this line is the one creating the mutiple instances of the MediaPayer
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    mp.setAudioAttributes(
           new AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build()
    );
    try {
          mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),newuri);
          mp.setDisplay(holder);
          mp.prepare();
          mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(Audio_Player.this);
          mycontroller=new MediaController(Audio_Player.this);
          mycontroller.setMediaPlayer(Audio_Player.this);
          mp.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

to

```
File mypath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
String mystring = (String) audiolist.getItemAtPosition(position);
if (mystring.contains(".mp3")) {
    File myfile = new File(mypath.toString(), "/" + mystring);
    Uri newuri = Uri.fromFile(myfile);
    // I think this line is the one creating the mutiple instances of the MediaPayer

    // Create a new MediaPlayer instance if there is no one existing.
    if (mp == null) {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        AudioAttributes.Builder builder = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA);
        mp.setAudioAttributes(builder.build());
        mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(Audio_Player.this);
        mycontroller = new MediaController(Audio_Player.this);
        mycontroller.setMediaPlayer(Audio_Player.this);
        mp.setDisplay(holder);
    }

    // If the MediaPlayer is playing, then stop it and switch to another audio,
    try {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.reset();
        }
        mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), newuri);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//end of if
```